# Compressing the binary file

Tags: c++

After deleting a record from the file, there could be an unused amount of memory in the file that was once occupied by the deleted record.  Many of these deleted records in the file can cause the file to grow very large but actually contain little useful data.  There are a couple of ways to avoid this:

1. Whenever a new record is inserted in the file, it could be inserted in the first available space in the file, not necessarily at the end.  However, this can lead to inefficiency if you search the file for the first available space - this would nullify the usefulness of the indexing structure for this operation.  You could maintain a simple queue that held the locationInFile of all records that had been deleted.  Whenever an insertion is required, an element could be retrieved (de-queued) from queue and used as the location to store the new record in the file. (Don’t forget to update the indexing structure).
2. After a certain threshold of deletions is reached (let’s use 5 deletions for example), the binary file would be compressed. This means that all of the valid records in the file would be moved to the beginning of the file (compressed to the beginning).  Consider the following picture where each square represents a place for a record in a file, each integer represents a valid record in use and each ‘x’ represents a deleted record:
   1 x x 2 x 3 x x 4

After the compression of the file, it would look something like:
1 2 3 4 x x x x x

Notice that all of the valid records are moved to the top of the file.  This method would require significant updates to your indexing structure.

**Any idea how I could implement this in code. Maybe a seek function can be useful. **

```
     // This program uses a structure variable to store a record to a file.
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

// Array sizes
const int SSN_SIZE = 10, NAME_SIZE = 51, ADDR_SIZE = 51, PHONE_SIZE = 14;

// Declare a structure for the record.
 struct Info {
    char ssn[SSN_SIZE];
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    char phone[PHONE_SIZE];
 };
 int main() {
    Info person;   // To hold info about a person
    char again;    // To hold Y or N
    // Open a file for binary output.
    fstream people("people.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    do {
        // Get data about a person.
        cout << "Enter the following data about a " << "person:\n";
        cout << "SSN: ";
        cin.getline(person.ssn, SSN_SIZE);
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin.getline(person.name, NAME_SIZE);
        cout << "Age: ";
        cin >> person.age;
        cin.ignore(); // Skip over the remaining newline.
        cout << "Phone: ";
        cin.getline(person.phone, PHONE_SIZE);

        // Write the contents of the person structure to the file.
        people.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person), sizeof(person));

        // Determine whether the user wants to write another record.
        cout << "Do you want to enter another record? ";
        cin >> again;
        cin.ignore(); // Skip over the remaining newline.
    } while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y');

    // Close the file.
    people.close();

    people.open("people.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!people) {
        cout << "Error opening file. Program aborting.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Here are the people in the file:\n\n";
    // Read the first record from the file.
    people.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person),
        sizeof(person));
    // While not at the end of the file, display the records.
    while (!people.eof()) {
        // Display the record.
        cout << "Name: ";
        cout << person.name << endl;
        cout << "Age: ";
        cout << person.age << endl;
        cout << "Address line 1: ";
        cout << person.address1 << endl;
        cout << "Address line 2: ";
        cout << person.address2 << endl;
        cout << "Phone: ";
        cout << person.phone << endl;

              // Wait for the user to press the Enter key.
        cout << "\nPress the Enter key to see the next record.\n";
        enter code here`cin.get(again);

            // Read the next record from the file.
        people.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person),
        sizeof(person));

    }



        cout << "That's all the data in the file!\n";
        people.close();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: Well I'm making a program where you store someone SSN address name and age. I need to find a way to delete the recorded information without the data file becoming to large so I have to track which record has been deleted.

Comment: What you're describing is usually called defragmentation rather than compression. Googling that term might turn up some helpful information.

Comment: If the data is small enough, read everything and write everything each time (no empty data), or if the data is too big, use a database.

Comment: You may want to research the topic of *memory fragmentation* to find algorithms.  I agree with @crashmstr, if the data is too big, use a database.

Comment: I would just like to add that writing a struct directly to a file from memory and reading directly from a file, is a bad idea. There's dozens of potential portability problems in that hole. Better to use a proper serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things you Need to think about... You Need to make sure to have enough space at the target Position (no overlapping)...

Actually this is the functionality of a filesystem, so why reinvent the wheel?

E.g. on Linux you can create a filesystem [inside a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/create-file-image-container) and then [mount it](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-mount-img-file-882386/). Then you can create a file for each person and save it in the filesystem. This way you are (almost) sure to have no bugs and receive security updates.

If you are not on Linux you can probably use some filesystem (NTFS, EXT4...) c++ apis to directly use the file as filesystem.

If you don't like that idea, I suggest to re-create the entire file and then delete the old file. Of course you only re-create it with the non-deleted entries.

**Last but no leaset:** If your file is very small then I think you actually don't Need defragmentation at all.